# Django get an instance of a object and pass it through to a form

Tags: django

I am new to Django and programming in general. I am trying to generate a list of records from a database but with two fields that can be edited.
In the browser it should show a line with the fields:
clientcode, clientname, Reason, comment
Name and description come from the model and are a reference. The user should only be able to capture reason and comments

I have created a forms.py file and a ModelForm. My issue is how do I pass through an individual object. For this example I've limited my dataset to 10 records
In my view file

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        nca = NcaRe.objects.all()[:10]
        form = NcaReForm(instance= <what should go in here> )
        return render(request, 'NCAComments/home.html', {'form': form, 'nca': nca})
    else:
        pass
```

In my model I have a field called primarykey. I'm not sure how to pass this to the form so that I only bring in that record. I have tried looking at the documentation but have not been able to follow it.

My Model py.

```
from django.db import models


class NcaRe(models.Model):
    primarykey = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=False, primary_key=True)
    clientcode = models.CharField(db_column='ClientCode', max_length=200, blank=True, null=True) 
    clientname = models.CharField(db_column='ClientName', max_length=510, blank=True, null=True)
    reason = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    comment = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'NCA_RE'
```

Forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import NcaRe

class NcaReForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = NcaRe
        fields = ['reason', 'comment']
```

In html I am trying to loop through and pass the form

```
{% for n in nca %}
<p> {{n.clientcode}}</p>
<form>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include forms.py and models.py in it?

Comment: Edited to include the forms, models and what I am trying to achieve with the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you need to just return empty form if the method of request if `GET` like as `form()`. I write below sample code that you can do your calculation in after form validation `form.is_valid()`

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from testPhilip.forms import NcaReForm
from testPhilip.models import NcaRe


def home(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        nca = NcaRe.objects.all()[:10]
        form = NcaReForm()

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = NcaReForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:

    return render(request, 'testPhilip/home.html', {'form': form, 'nca': nca})
```

You can retrieve the data after form validation in a cleaned format like this:
`comment = form.cleaned_data['comment']`

Update:

If you want to populate your form fields with values from database or any default values, you can pass them in the 'GET' section as below:

```
nca_object=NcaRe.objects.get(pk=nca_id)
form=NcaReForm({
    'comment':nca_object.comment,
    'reason':nca_object.reason,
})
```

For more information about writing forms refer to [Django forms doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#the-view)

Comment: Thanks. In this case I am looking more for an update/put option. Reason and comment could already be populated so I would want them to be returned and updated. That's why I am looking to return the instance in the loop. Its from an existing database table so I have initial values in many instances.

Comment: @PhilipSeimenis I updated the answer to have your request.

Comment: I can get this working if I pass through the primary key as an instance. When I try the above code I am getting errors. The problem is I have multiple forms on the same page like a list